# How to strip string and group by?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
print(df.groupby(['run_time','match_datetime',]).size())


run_time                    match_datetime     
2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391  2021-08-05 00:00:00    1
                            2021-08-06 06:00:00    1
                            2021-08-06 07:00:00    1
                            2021-08-06 08:00:00    1
                            2021-08-06 08:30:00    2
                                                  ..
2022-02-25 20:30:22.157029  2022-03-03 19:45:00    1
                            2022-03-03 20:00:00    1
                            2022-03-03 20:15:00    2
                            2022-03-03 21:00:00    1
                            2022-03-03 23:30:00    1
Length: 44544, dtype: int64

new df:
```

I want for every runtime, the top 2 dates from match_datetime e.g.

```
run_time                    match_datetime     
2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391  2021-08-05 
                            2021-08-06 
2022-02-25 20:30:22.157029  2022-03-03 
                            2022-03-02
```

How can I do it?

Also, on the same line, I tried to look yo convert the datetime to date but I was unable to find a solution for it ipso locum..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) or [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) for remove times, then [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) for sorted counts, so for top 2 rows per groups use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df['match_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['match_datetime'])

s = (df['match_datetime'].dt.normalize()
                         .groupby(df['run_time'])
                         .value_counts()
                         .groupby(level=0)
                         .head(2))
print (s)

run_time                    match_datetime
2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391  2021-08-06        5
                            2021-08-05        1
2022-02-25 20:30:22.157029  2022-03-03        6
Name: match_datetime, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I did `pd.to_datetime(df['match_datetime'])

s = (df['match_datetime'].dt.normalize()
                         .groupby(df['run_time'])
                         .value_counts()
                         .groupby(level=0)
                         .head(2))
print(s)` and I got `File "C:\Users\harsh\My Drive\Oddsportal\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py", line 506, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: @leonardo need `df['match_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['match_datetime'])`, added to answer.

Comment: How do I include more columns to the df with the same logic? but adding groupby to the level of `run_time`

Comment: @leonardo - do you need aggregate by `run_time` and some another column? then change `.groupby(df['run_time'])` to `.groupby([df['run_time'], df['new']])`

Comment: I need to aggregrate by runtime but then add all the other columns for every `runtime` and `match_datetime` values. This approach filters top two rows for this condition which is not what I want.